# jQuery div transition

Tags: jquery

I have a list a links and a few sections of content

```
<a href="#one">ORANGE</a>
<a href="#two">BLUE</a>
<a href="#three">PINK</a>
<a href="#four">GREEN</a>

<div id="hello">
    <section id="one">gfgfgfgf</section>
    <section id="two">gfgfgfgf</section>
    <section id="three">gfgfgfgf</section>
    <section id="four">gfgfgfgf</section>
</div>​
```

With each of the links corresponding to one of the content sections. I want to slide the `<section>` from the right when the corresponding link is clicked.

I've tried to play around with this a bit with no success. I just can't grasp the logic behind it. Here is my attempt.

http://jsfiddle.net/5N3YK/

Feel free to call me stupid, but please don't down vote me. I have tried in different ways with varying results, but I've reverted back to the one that would make most logical sense.

UPDATE: I forgot to write in the original post - I want the old one to slide out and the new one to slide in

Comment: we need a bit more information.  Technically they are sliding from the right.  Do you want them to stop?  Do you want them in a specific order (as in, always blue next to orange) or do you just want the correct one to overtake the existing one.  Do you want the old one to slide out?  We need more information.  Please be more descriptive

Comment: sorry, I want the old one to slide out and the new one to slide in

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this : http://jsfiddle.net/5N3YK/20/

Far from perfect, do not use it without changes. It's more an exemple showing how you could build it than a ready-made solution.

Hope it helps though, good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

http://jsfiddle.net/UDt7q/6/

but not optimal ofcourse.